# Regular expression causing segfault/stack overflow

Tags: regex, regex-negation, boost-xpressive

(or so I think)...

I'm using boost::xpressive as my regular expression engine to parse something and I get a segfault. I suspect that recursivity and my bad regular expression are to blame, because gdb shows more than 300 stack frames. So, here is my (case-sensitive) regular expression, in perl/python notation:

```
begin([^e]+)e((?:[^b]|b(?!egin))+)
```

which I expect to match

```
beginHEADER HEREeFOLLOWED BY SOME LONG LONG TEXT THAT GOES UNTIL NEXTbegin
```

with the first uppercase text (*HEADER HERE*) in the first group, and the second uppercase text in the second group. I always get the segfault if the text that should match group 2 is very long.

Why shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your regular expression a lot by simply using [non-greedy matching](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/xpressive/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide/creating_a_regex_object.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.creating_a_regex_object.static_regexes.static_xpressive_syntax_cheat_sheet):

```
begin(.+?)e(.+?)begin
```

Try that and see if it works better.

It's likely that your original regex was causing a stack overflow due to a recursive implementation of the `|`-or grouping in your regex, which was potentially branching with every single character in your second group.

A simple non-greedy `.+?` on the other hand doesn't need to branch for every single character.

Comment: I would keep `[^e]+` in the left hand part, it will probably perform better.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. This backtracking thing is mind-numbing.

Comment: Also, xpressive works a lot better when compiled in release-mode (maybe tail-recursion helps?).

Comment: Not tail recursion. Compiling in release mode causes many function calls to be inlined, resulting in more efficient use of the stack.